# What are some psychologically normal reasons for a parent to reject their child?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology

In family psychology are there any normal (not abnormal) reasons to give up and cut off communication with your child (adult or otherwise)? I would think it would be rational to have a closed adoption of a baby and communication might need to stop if the child presents a constant danger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [cuckolded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckold) father would be likely to reject a child who is discovered to not be his own. From evolutionary perspective, men who get cuckolded and take care of a genetically-distant man's child would fail to reproduce their own genes and increase the chance of survival of the genes of the other man who did the cuckolding. Thus rejecting such a child would be an evolutionary adaptation to the [problem of paternity uncertainty](http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~rakison/bussandschmitt.pdf).

Another reason could be that the mother misjudged the commitment of the father, and mated before such bond was established. This could be in combination with a father who's mating strategy favors [fertilizing high quantity of women](http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~rakison/bussandschmitt.pdf) over investing in few offspring with one woman.